# How to copy only non-collapsed portions of code in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio

I am working on an ASP.NET Framework MVC application that has a class with many properties, each of which has data annotations that are collapsed. Here is an un-collapsed example:

```
[Sample DataAnnotation1]
[Sample DataAnnotation2]
Public Property TestProperty As String
```

Here is the collapsed version of the same example:

```
Public Property TestProperty As String
```

Is it possible to copy this section of code in a way to where only the latter example gets copied to my clipboard instead of the former? In other words, is there a way to copy only the visible portion of collapsed code?

Thank you in advance for your help. I am a junior developer, so I apologize if my question has an obvious answer or has been addressed elsewhere.

Comment: can you give a specific example about your un-collapsed example? Based on my search, I can not find the example.

Answer (score 1):

The only answer I know to this is to hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and only copy the portions of the code that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for joining the party late on this one but the best way I can find to do this is use a block selection.

1. Click the start of where you want to start the copy at.
2. While holding down `SHIFT` + `ALT`, press the down arrow or the right arrow to create the block selection area.
3. Let go of `SHIFT` + `ALT`.
4. Use `Ctrl` + `C`.